# How to present the user a way to save which view of the homepage they want to see?

Tags: homepage, users, prompt, many-options

I want to give the user the ability to select from 5 different homepage views and save it as their default (in a cookie). The views are based on the type of user they are:

- **generic**
- **parent**
- **student**
- **teacher**
- **school**

There is also no login, so no way to present the view depending on their assigned role.

The first time the user visits the site (or first session) there will be a banner that  introduces the concept of setting that view as your default.

[image]

Once that prompt is dismissed, I want the user to have the ability to select or change which view he wants to be the default homepage without the prompt coming up every time.

I thought of a drop down on the top right, but I already have one for language and one for country. Also thought of adding a drop-down where the view types are, but it just dose not look good, seems off.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend to place *Role* link into options menu, where you already have *Country* and *Language* items.

For usability reasons user need learn how to change the Role and system should provide visual feedback of the current state. To achieve this you can use sticky tooltip, which points to *Role* control and contains description for user. Please see the image below, rightmost area is options menu.

To draw user's attention you can use animation when displaying this hint.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Both *Language* and *Country* are settings that change the entire page. Seems like this *Role* setting does too so I'd go with your intuition and stick it up there - and just do your best to visually separate it.

Another option would be to have the top left 'Logo' look different depending on what role you are, and make the logo itself a dropdown menu - which would allow you to select the different versions of the site.

Comment: The logo can't really change. Another thought I had was to put the language, role and country options inside a single dropdown. Gonna think that one through tonight and post it back if I come up with something.